# Add ligatures to Rmarkdown code

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am using the font DejaVu Sans Code for my code blocks in R markdown, but only some of the code ligatures are working, for example, the following code:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
monofont: DejaVu Sans Code
---

Here is some code:

```{r}
x <- 5 + 10
y <- (x != 15)
```
````

Produces:

[image: Example output]

The `!=` ligature works, but not the `<-` one, is there a way to fix this? Possibly using fontspec `Ligatures=` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use Sweave with XeLaTeX as the compiler.

Borrowing code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294369/100529):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Code}

\makeatletter
\def\verbatim@nolig@list{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
<<>>=
x <- 5 + 10
y <- (x != 15)
@

\begin{verbatim}
== != ~= === !== <!-- <-- <- -> --> <= >= => <=> ++ ::
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

gives this:

[image: Result]

with all the ligatures correct.